# geo nodes - scale top faces / edges from center along the track line

Tags: node-editor, transforms, geometry

ave gratis plenum

i need to scale top faces ( or edges ) of railroad track cutter

start mesh is .obj file exported from steam's rolling line game - railroad track mesh

track / terrain cutter is using geometry nodes

- it cuts railroad track into terrain ( mesh )
- using existing / imported track mesh - bottom ballast part ( mesh - *track* object in attached .blend file )
- in 3d viewport *edit mode* track bottom ( ballast part ) is manually selected , duplicated [ shift-d ] & separated [ p ] into track cutter base ( mesh )
- geo nodes ( gn cutter ) are attached to this track cutter base
- gn cutter does :
- remove top faces from track cutter base mesh - bottom faces remain
- bottom faces represent track line , which i want to use for terrain cutting
- from bottom faces , outer edges are selected & extruded upwards ( cutter height gn settings ) , making side faces
- next side faces are extruded ( cutter width gn settings ) - cutter is widened , to get track width
- next i select top faces / edges -> i want those faces / edges to scale outward along track line

i want to get V shape cut into terrain mesh , along track line = sloped sides , flat bottom , like shown on image below

tried many answers from many a sites , plus few days of trial & error :

- used **top** socket from **extrude mesh** connected to **scale elements** node **selection** socket
- tried various **position** & **edge vertices** & **math** & **vector math** node combinations , connected to **scale elements** node **selection** socket
- also tried connecting various node combinations into **scale elements** node , **center** socket - i think this is where i should try to tell geo nodes to **scale from individual faces / edges along track line**

managed to scale it half-correct - it scales the top faces / edges on either side of track line , from the top faces center , but i need to scale on both sides along track line - outwards

q : with top faces of cutter gn selected , how do i manage **scale elements** node **center** socket to scale selected top faces ( or edges ) , along track line ( as center line ) , on each side outwards ?

<- track ( middle ) line ->

like zis :
[image: real-world example of v-sloped track sides]

EDIT : track needs to be widened - if long train wagons or locomotive is running on curve , it will ' cut the corner ' ( image below )

[image: long wagon cutting the corner]

additional info is in attached .blend file

.blend file :
[gn.terrain.b41-alpha.scale.top.question.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ROkov8j_2_9qpFZjS0gEmMYc9rErSbCW/view?usp=drive_link)

file is made in b4.1-alpha , can be opened no problem in b4.0.2

thank you for your help

Comment: Hi, this is not a commissions forum, please explain your issue within the question body - you almost managed, but it's not clear what geometry you start with. If it's a curve, all you need is to bevel it with a trapezoid profile.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Sorry, but it's hard to discern what you're asking here. Could you clarify what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried and where exactly you're having issues?

Comment: i added additional explanation as requested in above comments ; thank you for clarifying

Comment: Can you add a question sentence with a  question mark to the post please?

Comment: i clarified the issue - added question sentence , as requested ; thank you for clarifying

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady - this is my plan B - extract center line from existing track mesh edges , convert to curve , and try to use that as a cutter for terrain ; for now i stick to plan A ( issue as described in this question ) , want to learn how to use **center** socket of **scale elements** node

Comment: honestly , i am not sure if i am on the right track ( lol ) , probably there are other better ways to achieve cutting terrain , from existing track line mesh , but this is what i have at the moment

Comment: [How to upload a blend file on BSE - good practices and advice](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3051/60486) - read this and also look around how other questions look on BSE, especially those highly voted up. [How to ask](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2620/60486) - Preparing the .blend file to be as simple as possible to capture your problem (get rid of the parts of the track that aren't the part of the problem, just keep the duplicated part) will hugely increase the chances someone will actually help

Answer (score 3):

This is your starting geometry:

[image]

Manually <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>$\color{green}{█}\color{#888}{0█}$ *click* the edges on blue/red boundary to select the holes, and press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill them (on both sides!) so that you have a manifold hull:

[image]

Now you can take the advantage of the slopes on sides to have the growing profile, by simply extruding using the normals and selecting the faces pointing up:

[image]

You could alter this side slope by moving the (top) vertices up:

[image]

After adjusting the εpsilon for the 3rd time and using "Math: Divide" to easily adjust very small $z$ offsets, you can fine-tune the angle like this:

[image]

The end result with *Merge by Distance* added to deal with internal faces of the cutter, and of course the boolean at the end:

[image]

Of course if you wanted to specify an exact angle of the slope, you could - you would just pass that to the "Extrude" direction, calculate the angle of the normal from the vertical, and if it's not 0 (not the top face), then multiply the xy component of the normal by the ratio of wanted angle divided by current angle…

Comment: you are a gem . love the answer . however , i would still need this step : next side faces are extruded ( cutter width gn settings ) - cutter is widened , to get track width ; so i extruded side faces again , and got good results ; but the extruded sides will ' stick ' below the track level , which might be desirable ; i additionally tried to select outer edges of gn cutter (v2) with intention to raise those edge up on z axis ,which would flatten the bottom of cut-out track

Comment: i added an image of long wagon ' cutting the corner ' - this is why i need to widen the base of track

Answer (score 1):

big thanks to
Markus von Broady

using his marvelous answer , i add 2 more nodes :

- extrude mesh to widen the track
- set position to move sides up / down

final solution :
[image: markus solution with 2 additional nodes]

it works like a charm , with additional cutting possibilities ...

[image: widen track & adjust sides]

have fun

EDIT : have no idea why .gif files are messy